# Can't install PyQt5 using pip on raspberry pi

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi, pyqt5, raspbian

On a raspberry pi using raspbian buuster, am I trying to install PyQt5 using

```
pip install PyQt5
pip3 install PyQt5
sudo -H pip install PyQt5
python3 -m pip install PyQt5
python3 -m pip install PyQt5 --user
```

All of these commands yields

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-rsse8fpi/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple --extra-index-url https://www.piwheels.org/simple -- 'sip >=5.0.1 <6' 'PyQt-builder >=1.1.0, <2'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (1 lines):
  ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'sip >=5.0.1 <6'
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-rsse8fpi/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple --extra-index-url https://www.piwheels.org/simple -- 'sip >=5.0.1 <6' 'PyQt-builder >=1.1.0, <2' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Other libraries can be installed, it's just PyQt5. What is preventing me from installing just PyQt5 and how can it be fixed?

Comment: You could install via apt: package `sudo apt install python3-pyqt5`

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem

Comment: Comma is missing in `sip >=5.0.1 <6`, it must be `sip >=5.0.1, <6`

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't solve the problem, as any other pip3 package depending on pyqt5 will also fail to install.

Answer (score -3):

from my experience installing pyqt5 is a little bit (toxic)
and u need to be very careful when installing it
what is the IDE that you use for python? 
if it is Pycharm then (delete it and install it again) but make sure you ADD Python PATH 
[image]

after you reinstall it (restart your pc ) then cmd
-pip install pyqt5

Comment: The original question refers to Raspbian Buster, so it's about a Linux-based system.

Comment: The answer may be useful for someone but is not related to the question.