# Unable to install PyQt5 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, pyqt, raspberry-pi, pyqt5

I am trying to install PyQt5 on my Raspberry Pi machine.

I have tried:

```
pip3 install pyqt5

pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install pyqt5==5.14.0

sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```

they all give me the error:

```
  Using cached PyQt5-5.14.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
ERROR: pyqt5==5.14 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/5b/e760ec4f868cb77cee45b4554bf15d3fe6972176e89c4e3faac941213694/PyQt5-5.14.0.tar.gz#sha256=0145a6b7de15756366decb736c349a0cb510d706c83fda5b8cd9e0557bc1da72 has a pyproject.toml file that does not comply with PEP 518: 'build-system.requires' contains an invalid requirement: 'sip >=5.0.1 <6'
```

Comment: It seems there's a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59558343/cant-install-pyqt5-on-raspberry-pi

Answer (score 5):

Please try :

```
sudo apt install python3-pyqt5
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to install `PyQt5==5.14.0`

https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/5.14.0/#files

`PyQt5-5.14.0.tar.gz\PyQt5-5.14.0.tar\PyQt5-5.14.0\pyproject.toml`

```
# Specify the build system requirements.
[build-system]
requires = ["sip >=5.0.1 <6", "PyQt-builder >=1.1.0, <2"]
build-backend = "sipbuild.api"

# Specify the PEP 566 metadata for the project.
[tool.sip.metadata]
name = "PyQt5"
version = "5.14.0"
summary = "Python bindings for the Qt cross platform application toolkit"
home-page = "https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/"
author = "Riverbank Computing Limited"
author-email = "info@riverbankcomputing.com"
license = "GPL v3"
description-file = "README"
```

`sip >=5.0.1 <6` is not a valid PEP518 format. It should be `sip >=5.0.1, <6`

In `PyQt5==5.14.1` this error was fixed.