# hello, how to fix this errors? im trying to install pyqt5 tools using 'pip install pyqt-tools'

Tags: pyqt5

ERROR: pyqt5==5.14.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/5b/e760ec4f868cb77cee45b4554bf15d3fe6972176e89c4e3faac941213694/PyQt5-5.14.0.tar.gz#sha256=0145a6b7de15756366decb736c349a0cb510d706c83fda5b8cd9e0557bc1da72 (from pyqt5-tools) has a pyproject.toml file that does not comply with PEP 518: 'build-system.requires' contains an invalid requirement: 'sip >=5.0.1 <6'

Answer (score 0):

See here -> [Unable to install PyQt5 on Raspberry Pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64930157/unable-to-install-pyqt5-on-raspberry-pi)

You have the same problem even if your not using a Raspberry Pi.

The version of pyqt-tools you're trying to install is using `PyQt5==5.14.0`  In the pyproject.toml file for PyQt5, `sip >=5.0.1 <6` is not a valid PEP518 format. It should be `sip >=5.0.1, <6`

In `PyQt5==5.14.1` this error was fixed.  Thus, you'll need to use a version of pyqt-tools that depends on PyQt5 >= 5.14.1